# "Font Awsome Icons" Multiplication Miracle ?|

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Im having trouble figuring out what am i doing wrong.

This is my code

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li></li>
        <li><a href="#" onClick="reloadPage()">Refrescar</a></li>
        <li><a href="facebook_link" <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i></li>
        <li><a href="picasa_link" <i class="fa fa-camera fa-lg"></i></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

this is Dreamweaver preview:
http://prntscr.com/34l5x9

And this is the result im getting on google chrome:
http://prntscr.com/34l64g

Why is the reason this is happening?
And how can i change the code to fix it?

Comment: `<a href="facebook_link" <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i>` isn't valid HTML.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't correctly closed your `<a>` tags:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li></li>
        <li><a href="#" onClick="reloadPage()">Refrescar</a></li>
        <li><a href="facebook_link"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="picasa_link"><i class="fa fa-camera fa-lg"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks i feel stupid now, i should go to sleep this istant!

Answer (score 0):

Several issues here with your `html`. You need to close tags after you open them and you cannot place an `<i>` inside of another element as you have done.

try this:

```
<div>
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" onClick="reloadPage()">Refrescar</a></li>
       <li><a href="facebook_link"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="picasa_link"><i class="fa fa-camera fa-lg"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="facebook_link" <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i></li>
<li><a href="picasa_link" <i class="fa fa-camera fa-lg"></i></li>
```

Should be:

```
<li><a href="facebook_link"> <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="picasa_link"> <i class="fa fa-camera fa-lg"></i></a></li>
```

your `<a></a>`'s weren't valid